# How to Convert Output into 00:00 format in DateTime in c#

Tags: c#

I subtracted my input time to my time and I want my output into 00:00 format please help me on these

```
DateTime timein = new DateTime("5:00 am");
var a = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var b = a - timein;
```

please I want my output 
00:00 format

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if `b` is your output variable then:

```
String b = (a - timein).ToString("hh:mm tt"); //for 12 hour format with AM or PM.

String b = (a - timein).ToString("HH:mm"); //for 24 hour format.
```

As seen here on MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is how to format `00:00`, not a full-blown date and time. Also, `DateTimeVariable` doesn't exist in the question. Use `b` instead.

Comment: Updated to reflect @QualityCatalyst comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could format by using format specifiers in `ToString` method [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0rmTnx). Your code has to look like:

```
DateTime timein = DateTime.Parse("5:00 am");
var a = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var b = a - timein;
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```